# Angular2 datatable with high volume of data

Tags: java, spring, angular

I want to show high volume of data on a datatable. I am using Angular2 for my UI and spring REST API for backend. How can I design my dataable with pagination and filters to smoothly handle high volume of data. How will I design my backend for this requirement.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-pagination-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a paginated REST service.

Let's say we want to show in a datatable all the users in our database.

We will have a method with the following signature :

```
public ResponseEntity<PaginatedResponse<User>> getUsers(
            @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size)
```

Here we are sending the page number and the size of each page in the request.

We define the response :

```
public class PaginatedResponse<T> {

    private List<T> responseList;

    private int pageNumber;

    private int pageSize;

    private int totalPageNumber;
}
```

In the response we will have the total number of pages and the size of the current page, along with its index.

For the data layer you can use spring Data :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>
```

And declare the method to extract the pageable data :

```
@Query("select u, from User u")
    Page<User> findUsers(final Pageable pageable);
```

Note that you can add parameters to filter your spring data query using `@Param` annotation.

As for the angular part, you will have to iterate over http calls to get the data and each time check if the page index is in the range ( i.e < totalPageNumber)